# Time gap and header reprint in IIS6 logs

Tags: iis, iis-6, log-files, logging

We had some users complaining about a web service not responding periodically, so I took a look in my IIS logs, and found that periodically, there are time-gaps and a reprint of the header that coincide with the times that customers are saying that they see connection timeout errors.

Does anyone know if this is 'normal' or if it indicates a problem? If it indicates a problem, is there a means for diagnosis?

My log files look like (parts removed for readability):

```
2009-11-09 23:31:16 W3SVC713846796 SERVER 1.2.3.4 POST /page1.aspx - 443 - 1.2.3.4  ...
2009-11-09 23:31:18 W3SVC713846796 SERVER 1.2.3.4 GET /page2.aspx - 443 - 1.2.3.4 ...
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2009-11-09 23:55:48
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken 
2009-11-09 23:55:48 W3SVC713846796 SERVER 1.2.3.4 POST /page1.aspx - 443 - 1.2.3.4  ...
2009-11-09 23:55:48 W3SVC713846796 SERVER 1.2.3.4 POST /page2.aspx - 443 - 1.2.3.4  ...
...
...
2009-11-09 23:55:52 W3SVC713846796 SERVER 1.2.3.4 POST /page2.aspx - 443 - 1.2.3.4  ...
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2009-11-10 00:18:43
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken 
2009-11-10 00:18:43 W3SVC713846796 SERVER 1.2.3.4 GET /page3.aspx - 443 - 1.2.3.4  ...
```

this is all within a single log file. It just seems to have large gaps of several minutes and a header reprint... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further inspection, it seems that this is related to the worker process hitting its idle timeout and shutting down. On the next request, it starts back up and reprints a header in the log.

[Configuring Worker Processes for Idle Timeout (MS TechNet)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83b35271-c93c-49f4-b923-7fdca6fae1cf.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

When you see the header repeated like this, it typically means IIS was restarted.  Any Event Log entries?

Comment: No there was nothing int he event logs. I'm thinking this is just normal IIS behavior though, becuase on further review, I get the same gaps and headers for all the sites in all the servers in the farm, and with gaps up to a few hrs at night. So i think it must just shut down the threads or something if idle for too long and reinitialize on a request.